# Diplaying records of last month and year

Tags: mysql

I am having a table in MYSQL in which among other fields i am having two fields one for Month (Varchar) and year (int). Months field is used to store the name of the month and year is used to store the year of the entered data. I am confused that how can use the where class to display only the records of max month and year.
For Example

```
10 records are there for month January 2013
50 records are there for month February 2013
.
.
.
100 records are there for the month of November 2014 --- (LAST ENTRY)
```

Now
HERE I want to display only the November 2014 records. My code is written in such a way that i can not use the select query, I have to do it using WHERE CLAUSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE
  (year, month) = (SELECT year, month
                   FROM tablename
                   ORDER BY
                     STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', '01', month, year), '%d %M %Y') DESC
                   LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Its not working ....  :-(  Giving error to use "right syntax to use near ''%d %M %Y))"

Comment: @Ricky i forgot one `'` and removed one extra `)` it should be okay now

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), year, month
from your_table
group by year, month
order by year,
         case when month = 'January' then 1
              when month = 'February' then 2
              when month = 'March' then 3
              when month = 'April' then 4
              when month = 'May' then 5
              when month = 'June' then 6
              when month = 'July' then 7
              when month = 'August' then 8
              when month = 'September' then 9
              when month = 'October' then 10
              when month = 'November' then 11
              when month = 'December' then 12
     end desc
limit 1
```

Comment: My code is written in such a way that i can not use the select query, I have to do it using WHERE CLAUSE

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select Count(*),month,year from tablename 
group by STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', '01', month, year), '%d %M %Y') order by
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', '01', month, year), '%d %M %Y')
```